# jQuery DatePicker, how to show value in input field from database

Tags: php, jquery

can't find solution to this issue. So i have datepicker input field, it works fine, i can choose date and save it to database. But when i want to edit this saved value in edit_profile.php this field is empty, i need to see the user specified date. How to do it?

Datepicker function:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",   
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    }).val('<?php echo $age;?>');

});
```

Input:

`<input name="datepicker" type="text" id="datepicker" class="date_picker" value="" />`

what to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do this:-

```
<input name="datepicker" type="text" id="datepicker" class="date_picker" value="<?php echo $age;?>" >
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use defaultDate option, for example

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, defaultDate: yourDate });
```

Comment: When i use your script, the calendar won't open on input click, ant date value isn't shown. Maybe i do something wrong with this : 'defaultDate: $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", "2009 09 09")' .

Comment: From documentation: "Specify either an actual date via a Date object or as a string in the current dateFormat, or a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +7d'), or null for today." So the best solution is to use javascript Date object in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SetDate or Defaultdate option of datepicker:

```
$('#dateselector').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2008,9,03) );
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to set the date from database? now i always see the date 2008,10,03. maybe i did something wrong ?

 $(function() {
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
 dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
 changeMonth: true, 
 changeYear: true
}); 
 
 $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2008,9,03) ); });